# How to create WL.BusyIndicator equivalent for Black Berry 10

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, blackberry-10

I am working on a worklight project and I need to have a busy indicator for BB10. I know WL.BusyIndicator does not support for bb10, what are some equivalent I could do?
I tried jquery mobile busy indicator, it does not look good. Since jquery mobile busy indicator runs on the same thread, sometimes it does not show up. I need the busy indicator to run the frontend on a different thread (a more natvie solution). Anyone has any suggestions? Thanks advance.

Comment: if my answer below helped you resolve your problem, please mark it as Answered.

Answer (score 1):

Worklight's `WL.BusyIndicator` *does* support BlackBerry 10. You will just see the web implementation rather than a native one (as seen in Android, iOS and Windows Phone 8).

Note that in the case of the web `WL.BusyIndicator`, you can customize its look & feel since it's basically CSS... [These are the classes to override](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZH4A_6.2.0/com.ibm.worklight.apiref.doc/html/refjavascript-client/html/WL.BusyIndicator.html?cp=SSZH4A_6.2.0%2F10-0-0-1-5&lang=en): `#WLbusyOverlay`, `#WLbusy` and `#WLbusyTitle`. Best here is to simply preview the app in your browser and use Chrome's DevTools (or equivalent) to tweak the classes and then copy them back to your app's .css file in Eclipse).

Additionally, you can use any number of Activity Indicators [found on the web](https://www.google.co.il/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=activity%20indicators%20javascript&safe=off).
[Spin.js looks good](http://fgnass.github.io/spin.js/).

And since you are targetting BlackBerry 10, you may want to take a look at [BlackBerry's own bbUI JavaScript toolkit](http://developer.blackberry.com/html5/documentation/v2_1/using_the_bbui_toolkit.html) and integrate it in your app:

> The bbUI toolkit is an open source JavaScript toolkit that allows you
>   to give your BlackBerry WebWorks applications the look and feel of a
>   native BlackBerry application.

bbUI [provides an Activity Indicator](https://github.com/blackberry/bbUI.js/wiki/Activity-Indicator).